# sync event pass results to application or listen for db events

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have following flow in my application:

1. set some data on the page and submit them [app]
2. save data in indexeddb and fire sync event [app]
3. retrieve data from indexeddb and send them to server [service-worker]
4. save response in indexeddb [service-worker]
5. retrieve response from indexeddb and publish to view [app]

The flow is working for me, but I am not happy with that how I have solved point 5. At this moment, after service worker is fired, in next line of app code I am fireing `setInterval` method to periodically check if there is new row in `responses` table .

Is there any way to send event from service-worker sync to application, to let it know that the data is waiting for it?

Or maybe there is an event on indexeddb, to which I can subscribe to listen for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set up a message channel between the ServiceWorker and your app. From a high level, communication from app to ServiceWorker will occur on one port of the channel and communication from the ServiceWorker back to the app will occur on a different port of the channel. Instead of polling for updated data, your ServiceWorker should just be able to inform your app that the response has successfully been saved.

Stumbled upon this blog post which should be able to get you started in the right direction: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/serviceworker-messagechannel-postmessage